# Single Android user on LG v20 cannot save to SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am a hobbyist with no formal coding background.  I created an Android app for people in my profession to keep records on their personnel.  I have 1600 active users, but only one (so far) is unable to insert data into the SQLite Database table.  He is using a LG v20 and sent me a screen shot, verifying that he is putting in all the required fields.  Three of the fields are "NOT NULL" and one of them must be " UNIQUE".  He also assured me that he hasn't been able to save anyone so the unique factor shouldn't be in play.  Has anyone else had this issue and found a workaround?  Below is my Database Helper code for this table.

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PERSONNEL = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_PERSONNEL + "(" + PERSONNEL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + RANK
        + " TEXT NOT NULL," + LAST_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + FIRST_NAME + " TEXT," + MIDDLE_NAME +
        " TEXT," + SECTION + " TEXT," + DODI + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL," + DOB + " DATETIME," + DOR + " DATETIME," +
        MOS + " TEXT," + DUTY_POSITION + " TEXT," + DEROS + " DATETIME," +
        ETS + " DATETIME," + BASD + " DATETIME," + ARRIVAL_DATE + " DATETIME," +
        CIV_ED + " TEXT," + MIL_ED + " TEXT," + ALLERGIES + " TEXT," + HOT_INJURY + " TEXT," +
        COLD_INJURY + " TEXT," + ADDRESS + " TEXT," + ADDRESS_CITY + " TEXT," + ADDRESS_STATE +
        " TEXT," + ADDRESS_ZIP + " TEXT," + PHONE + " TEXT," + NOK + " TEXT," + NOK_PHONE + " TEXT," +
        NOK_ADDRESS + " TEXT," + NOK_CITY + " TEXT," + NOK_STATE + " TEXT," + NOK_ZIP +
        " TEXT," + PROMOTABLE + " TEXT," + RANK_SORT + " INTEGER," + SUPER_DODI + " TEXT," +
        BLOOD_TYPE + " TEXT" + ")";


public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_PERSONNEL);
}


boolean insertPerson(String rank, String lastName, String firstName, String middleInitial,
                     String section, String dodi, String dob, String dor, String mos, String duty,
                     String deros, String ets, String basd, String arrival, String civEd,
                     String milEd, String allergies, String hot, String cold, String address, String city,
                     String state, String zip, String phone, String nok, String nokPhone,
                     String nokAddress, String nokCity, String nokState, String nokZip,
                     String promote, int rankSort, String superDodi, String blood){

    ContentValues personnelValues = new ContentValues();
    personnelValues.put(RANK, rank);
    personnelValues.put(LAST_NAME, lastName);
    personnelValues.put(FIRST_NAME, firstName);
    personnelValues.put(MIDDLE_NAME, middleInitial);
    personnelValues.put(SECTION, section);
    personnelValues.put(DODI, dodi);
    personnelValues.put(DOB, dob);
    personnelValues.put(DOR, dor);
    personnelValues.put(MOS, mos);
    personnelValues.put(DUTY_POSITION, duty);
    personnelValues.put(DEROS, deros);
    personnelValues.put(ETS, ets);
    personnelValues.put(BASD, basd);
    personnelValues.put(ARRIVAL_DATE, arrival);
    personnelValues.put(CIV_ED, civEd);
    personnelValues.put(MIL_ED, milEd);
    personnelValues.put(ALLERGIES, allergies);
    personnelValues.put(HOT_INJURY, hot);
    personnelValues.put(COLD_INJURY, cold);
    personnelValues.put(ADDRESS, address);
    personnelValues.put(ADDRESS_CITY, city);
    personnelValues.put(ADDRESS_STATE, state);
    personnelValues.put(ADDRESS_ZIP, zip);
    personnelValues.put(PHONE, phone);
    personnelValues.put(NOK, nok);
    personnelValues.put(NOK_ADDRESS, nokAddress);
    personnelValues.put(NOK_CITY, nokCity);
    personnelValues.put(NOK_STATE, nokState);
    personnelValues.put(NOK_ZIP, nokZip);
    personnelValues.put(NOK_PHONE, nokPhone);
    personnelValues.put(PROMOTABLE, promote);
    personnelValues.put(RANK_SORT, rankSort);
    personnelValues.put(SUPER_DODI, superDodi);
    personnelValues.put(BLOOD_TYPE, blood);
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_PERSONNEL, null, personnelValues);
    db.close();
    return result != -1;
}
```

And here is my activity code to insert the values.

```
public void savePerson() {
    getStrings();
    boolean inserted = dbHelper.insertPerson(rankString, lastString, firstString, miString,
            sectionString, dodiString, dobString, dorString, mosString, dutyString, derosString,
            etsString, basdString, arrivalString, civEdText, milEdText, allergiesText, hotText,
            coldText, addressString, cityString, stateString, zipString, phoneString, nokString,
            nokPhoneString, nokAddressString, nokCityString, nokStateString, nokzipString, promoteString,
            rankSort, superDodi, bloodString);
    if (inserted) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PersonDetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("DODI", dodiString);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Data not inserted - Check Rank, Last Name, and DODI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you have any error log?

Comment: What is the error? Does he get the toast?

Comment: @CL, I don't have an error log, he just gets the toast because 'insertPerson' returns false.  I'm not having the issue on my phone and I made sure I downloaded the latest version from the Play Store.

Comment: Use `insert()` only when you want to suppress any error messages. Better replace it with `insertOrThrow()`.